# cmd execution via CodeBlocks won't allow MS Gothic font

Tags: cmd, fonts, console-application, codeblocks, cjk

When I build my program in CodeBlocks, cmd displays two different font lists for "Defaults" and "Properties".

Defaults -> Font:
ＭＳゴシック (MS Gothic), Raster Fonts

Properties -> Font:
Consolas, Lucida Console, Raster Fonts

As a consequence I can't print Japanese characters via programs built in CodeBlocks. Even with MS Gothic seemingly selected as the Default, this is completely ignored for the final execution which only recognizes the fonts listed under "Properties".

When cmd is ran without CodeBlocks there is no discrepancy between the Defaults and Properties options: They both show MS Gothic and Raster Fonts. I would like to continue using CodeBlocks however.

Code example with random kanji for testing purposes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("chcp 65001 > nul");
    printf("姥栄泳");
    return 0;
}
```

What confounds me even more is that I was able to use this setup for a day or two before the cmd decided to be difficult. I have no idea what changed to make this error happen and undo my ability to print Japanese characters via Code::Blocks.

**Misc details**:

- OS - Windows 8.1 Pro, 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
- System Language set to Japanese (to allow the MS Gothic font so that JP characters can be printed at all in the cmd)
- Code::Blocks Ver 17.12
- GNU GCC Compiler, mingw32-g++.exe ver 5.1.0.
- Re-installing Code::Blocks has not solved the issue

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which also answered how I was able to print the Japanese text earlier.

In order to trick Code::Blocks into activating cmd with MS Gothic enabled, I first have to use a reference to the Shift JIS code page:

```
system("chcp 932 > nul");
```

Build the project with that character code page even though it won't print the Japanese characters properly (presumably since I am using characters with UTF-8 encoding rather than Shift JIS).

Then undo the reference to chcp 932 and change it to chcp 65001 instead. Build the project and now the cmd will be using MS Gothic and displaying the correct Japanese characters EVEN THOUGH it claims that the following fonts are only available for use:

Properties -> Font: Consolas, Lucida Console, Raster Fonts

If you select any of these fonts, even re-selecting the one currently selected, the cmd will realize that it can't use MS Gothic and so the Japanese characters will be replaced by squares instead.

I have no idea why Code::Blocks makes it so the cmd has to be tricked into a sort of "limbo" in order to accept MS Gothic but at least it is working for me once again.

Answer (score 1):

The `cmd` command shell is a legacy terminal emulator that can't "just do" other languages. It is incredibly dumb, and needs to be told how to decode bytecode based on the over 20 year old concept of Windows Codepages. If you want to see any Japanese at all, you'll have to first determine which encoding your text is actually using, like JSIS, EUC, ... - Looking at your code, there is a `chcp` instruction to use codepage 65001, but nothing that actually shows that's going to be the correct codepage based on what the compile will generate, so you'll have to find out which actual byte sequence it's outputting and then use the correct codepage based on what you know of the text, and of which codepages encode which text with which byte sequences.

Or, and this one's way easier: don't use `cmd` if you need a modern unicode compatible terminal emulator. If you do *any* kind of mixed language or unicode work, just use something like [Console2](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx), which I would recommend any day of the week. Your program will work just fine with its output rendered by that.